# Linear Algebra Prove Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve this textbook question but I really don't know how to proceed.

> Question: "Suppose that $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are elements in some vector
>   space. Let $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2 + 2X_3,\ Y_2 = X_1 + X_2 − X_3$. Prove that if $\{Y_1,
> > Y_2\}$ is linearly dependent then $\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$ is also dependent."

So far I have tried making a dependency equation by writing $$a(X_1+X_2+2X_3) + b(X_1+X_2-X_3) = 0$$. I tried solving the matrix but I do not know if what I did is right. Can anyone help me in telling me how to go about it or tell me if what I did was right? Thank you[image]

Comment: Why not just expand your brackets and rearrange for a dependency relation on the $X_i$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Since the $Y_i$ are not linearly independent, there exist $a,b$ not both zero satisfying the equation you wrote down. Rearrange the equation and look at the coefficient of each $X_i$. Can the $X_i$ be linearly independent?

Comment: From what I understood, I think you mean that in the matrix instead of writing X1, X2 and stuff I should just write their coefficients. But won't the result (the one that I got) be the same regardless? moreover the reason I didn't use a and b as the coefficients was because it would have been impossible to simplify them

Comment: Why do you need a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to solve a matrix to prove this.

If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are linearly dependent, there exist $a$ and $b$, not both zero, such that 
$$aY_1+bY_2=0$$
Replace the $Y_i$ by their $X_i$ counterpart.
$$a(X_1+X_2+2X_3)+b(X_1+X_2-X_3)=0$$
Reorganise the terms
$$(a+b)X_1+(a+b)X_2+(2a-b)X_3=0$$
It left to prove that $(a+b)$ and $(2a-b)$ can't both be zero.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your proof completely but I have a conceptual question. If (a+b) and (2a-b) can't be 0, then how does this prove that X1, X2, and X3 are linear dependent?

Comment: @AniketGupta we found a non-trivial linear combinaison of $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ that give the vector $0$. Hence they are linearly dependent.